# Why has finalization stopped?

Tags: grandpa, validator, finality, pallet-staking

[image]

So I have a `validator_count` of 2, and 1 as `minimum_validator_count`. My validator is always online. I had my friend make another validator, had it enter the active validator set, and then join in as a validator, but they had to shut down their machine. To my surprise, I see that now my chain has stopped finalizing blocks but it goes on producing blocks normally. All functions work.

I have 2 questions:

1. why does this happen?
2. And how can we fix this?

**Edit**:
Looking around I've found this : https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics/#grandpa
as a way to reinitialize the grandpa authority set (if I understand correctly), which might have been corrupted by 1/2 validators leaving.

I've also noted that the `roundState()` rpc call errors out with :  **`GRANDPA RPC endpoint not ready`**. An explanation for this would be welcome.

**Edit #2** : I've already fixed this using the tx.noteStalled. However I'd still like an answer to the first question. i.e why does this happen? Is it because of BFT and 1/2 validators turning out faulty?

**Edit #3** : And why is my **`GRANDPA RPC endpoint not ready`**?
[image]